# Delete last item in Browser History

Tags: javascript, browser, form-submit, browser-history

When a form is submitted to a URL, the browser registers the page again in the history. Suppose, I'm in Page X and I go to Page Y and submit the form. Now, when I press back button of the browser, it again loads the same Page ie. Page Y instead of going to Page X.
So, this form submission makes the browser register the Page Y in the browser history again.
And, I'm supporting all the browsers and devices.
How can I delete the last entry in the browser history or stop browser from registering the page again in history ?

Comment: couldn't you just have the form send the browser to Page X when it's done, so that people don't need to press the back button?

Comment: @tylermackenzie No, the user should remain in the same page as it has some more functionalities other than form submission. But even if I do a history.back(), it'll still be in the history and if user clicks the forward button then again, he has to click the back button twice to go to Page X if he wishes to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the users history. The best you can do in that regard is change where the back button of the current page points to with `location.replace(pageX)` so that pressing the back button doesn't reload the same page but goes to pageX. But problems will arise if the user presses back again because the history for that page will be pageY again.

Your best option is to keep the form submission from refreshing the page in the first place. That way the history will be correct. This can be done by sending the form with AJAX instead of the traditional method. Here is an example using jQuery to prevent the traditional form submission and then make the AJAX request.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                // if you want it to do something when it's done, put it here
            },
            error: alert("broke" ), 
            type: "GET"
        });
    });
});
```

**Update**

A third good option is to just do what you stated in your comment. If you use `history.back()` after the form is submitted, then the users **Back** history will work exactly as you want. pressing back once takes them to pageX. it will only be the **Forward** history that gets weird. But it would be extremely unlikely for forward button to be pressed. the user Just navigated to the page, why would they press forward? Then as soon as they navigate somewhere else, that weird forward history is overwritten.